# How can I follow dry method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to rails. So don't know how to follow the **DRY** method. lets dive into the question.

I have two method in my controller were I have followed the same code. So how can I reduce my code. In this two method only model name get difference. Please assist me

I need something like this

```
array = ['Userservice', 'Userschedule' ]
    array.each do |el|
        draft_info = el.find_by(user_id: 39, save_option: "publish")
        draft_info.delete if !draft_info.nil?
        @user_info = el.find_by(user_id: 39, save_option: "draft")
        el.create(@user_info.attributes.merge({:save_option => "publish", :id => el.maximum(:id).to_i.next }))
    end




def create_publish_user
    publish_user_schedule
    publish_user_service
end

def publish_user_service
 draft_service =  Userservice.where(user_id: current_user.id, save_option: "publish").delete_all
 user_service = Userservice.where(user_id: current_user.id, save_option: "draft")
 user_service.each { |ser|  
  Userservice.create(ser.attributes.merge({:save_option => "publish", :id => Userservice.maximum(:id).to_i.next }))
 }
end

def publish_user_schedule
 draft_schedule =  Userschedule.where(user_id: current_user.id, save_option: "publish").delete_all
 user_schedule = Userschedule.where(user_id: current_user.id, save_option: "draft")
 user_schedule.each { |sch|  
   Userschedule.create(sch.attributes.merge({:save_option => "publish", :id => Userschedule.maximum(:id).to_i.next }))
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you ought to be able to do something like:

```
['Userservice', 'Userschedule'].each do |el|
  el_class = el.constantize
  if draft_info = el_class.find_by(user_id: 39, save_option: "publish")
    draft_info.delete
  end
  @user_info = el_class.find_by(user_id: 39, save_option: "draft")
  el_class.create(
    @user_info.attributes.merge({
      save_option: :publish, 
      id: el_class.maximum(:id).to_i.next 
    })
  )
end
```

I don't know why you're specifying the `id` when you're doing `create`. Why would you do that instead of letting `ActiveRecord` take care of that for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an argument to your method

```
def publish(type)
  draft = type.where(....)
  data = type.where(....)
  data.each ....
  # And so on
end

# Somewhere in your code you use it then
publish(UserService)
```